# list category posts under its item in menu

Tags: menus, filters

When adding category to Menu, I need it to list all the item that belong to that category in separate `UL` automatically. like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulOOS.jpg
Of course I can do that manually, but I'm look for a way to add a filter, maybe, to the `wp page menu` function, but Im not sure how its can be done.
I'm using `thematic` child theme

Thank you.

Comment: I would like to know how to do this as well

Answer (score 0):

if you go to the menus page, then click on Screen Options in the top right of the page. You can select "Posts". This will allow you to add the post to the navigation menu. Then you just drag it under the category that it is in. You will need to make sure you are using a [custom menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)

Answer (score 0):

Start by browsing to **Appearance – Menus**. Select the menu where you want the link to be displayed. Create a new **Link menu item** and use # as the URL with the link text of categories. Then click the **Add to Menu button**.

### [image]

Select which categories you want to be displayed within the dropdown list. After you add the categories to the menu, make sure to drag and drop them so that they are a child link underneath the parent menu of categories. Look at the following screenshot for reference.

After you’ve arranged the category links, save the menu. Visit your front page and hover over the categories link to make sure the dropdown list works correctly. The parent menu item of categories acts as a placeholder which is the ingenious part of the tutorial.
[image]

After you’ve arranged the category links, save the menu. Visit your front page and hover over the categories link to make sure the dropdown list works correctly. The parent menu item of categories acts as a placeholder which is the ingenious part of the tutorial.

[image]